# How to use __init__.py to simplify imports

Tags: python, import

If I have a file structure like this:

```
file.py
utils
  - __init__.py
  - db.py
  - config.py
```

And db.py looks something like this

```
class DbClass():
  #class definition
  ...
```

Then in `file.py` I can import the `DbClass` class using:

```
   from utils.db import DbClass
```

I know I can edit `__init__.py` to change how things can be imported, but I'm struggling with understanding it.

What can I add to `__init__.py` so that I could import the Db class using:

```
import utils.DbClass
```

**Edit:**

Maybe that's not possible.

Is there a way to have `import utils.db` act like `from utils.db import DbClass` ?

Comment: `import utils.DbClass` - that won't work. You can get `from utils import DbClass` or `import utils` and `utils.DbClass` to work, but `import utils.DbClass` is the wrong syntax.

Comment: If you `import utils`th then `utils.DbClass` is there. Nothing else needs to happen. Under the covers, python added everything from `__init__.py` to the module namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DbClass` is not a module, you can only import it with `from x import y`. Instead, write in `file.py`

```
from utils import DbClass
```

and in `utils/__init__.py`

```
from .db import DbClass
```

Comment: Aha I think that's what I was looking for. I don't suppose there is anything more general. So if I had several files in utils would I have to add that line for each of them?

Comment: Yes, if you want to present classes or objects directly in the utils module, you have to import each of them in `__init__.py`